# How does the `-n` option to `image lookup` in LLDB operate compared to the `-s` option?

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, lldb

I know that the `-s` option searches the symbol table (`image dump symtab`) for symbols matching `<symbol>`.

However, I don't understand how the `-n` option operates. It returns different results from `-s`, and if it doesn't search the symbol table for functions/symbols, where does it look for `<function-or-symbol>`?

`help image lookup`:

```
-s <symbol> ( --symbol <symbol> )
            Lookup a symbol by name in the symbol tables in one or more target modules.

-n <function-or-symbol> ( --name <function-or-symbol> )
            Lookup a function or symbol by name in one or more target modules.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [GDB to LLDB command map reference](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#executable-and-shared-library-query-commands) says that:

```
This one finds debug symbols:
(lldb) image lookup -r -n <FUNC_REGEX>

This one finds non-debug symbols:
(lldb) image lookup -r -s <FUNC_REGEX>

Provide a list of binaries as arguments to limit the search.
```

So, `image lookup -n` only searches debug symbols, while `image lookup -s` searches non-debug symbols.

Answer (score 2):

In lldb, the "symbol table" means the table that the linker and loader use to go from names to callable objects.  So -s will NOT consult debug information.

lldb's convention is to use "function" as opposed to "symbol" to mean the representation of a callable object coming from the debug information.  So -n will consult both the linker/loader's symbol table information and debug info to match the given name.

Comment: thank you. However for a simple "HelloWorld" C-program, how can `-n` return fewer results than `-s` for the same search string?  According to your answer, `-s` will always be a subset of `-n` for the same search string. Also, by "linker", you mean "dynamic linker" invoked at run-time?

Comment: `-n` is supposed to look at both.  If it isn't, that's a bug.

Comment: As for "linker" I mean the symbol tables written by the linker.  If you look at the output of `nm` on a binary - that's the command that dumps the linker's symbol tables - you will see lots of `T` symbols - those are exported TEXT symbols - and those are the ones that the loader (== dynamic linker) reads.  But there are also lots of `t` symbols.  Those are unexported symbols that the loader won't read, but the linker puts them in the same table as the exported symbols.  `-s` will consult both exported and unexported symbols from the linker's symbol tables.

Comment: `t` symbols are always present in unstripped debug builds, but also OS frameworks will often leave in some of these unexported symbols because they make backtraces through the frameworks easier to understand.

Comment: thanks! I was under the expression that the linker only creates a single symbol table for a Mach-O object file (e.g. executable)? - or at most two, one for exported symbols and one for imported symbols.

Comment: Furthermore, the linker looks at imported symbols for an executable, right? It only considers exported symbols for shared libraries (.dylib).

Comment: There's only one symbol table, but each symbol in the table has a bitfield that specifies, among other things, whether the symbol is a definition of or a reference to a symbol, and whether it is exported or not.  Executables tend to only use symbols from other libraries, but for instance if an executable has a plugin architecture it might need to export the "register me as a plugin" function.  OTOH, shared libraries generally provide definitions, and use definitions from other shared libraries.  These are really just usage patterns, the loader works pretty much the same on all binary types.